# Some hint for this exercise? (Bayesian)

Tags: self-study, bayesian, modeling, hierarchical-bayesian

I have the following problem (BDA3), but I'm confused, because actually, I have 2 samples, and I don't know how to set up just one model (of course is a multiparameter model, but how can I use the independence?) and honestly, I can't see the difference between a) and b). Guys, I just want a HINT, because I really have a mental blank

(a) Let $y_{1}, . . . , y_{10}$ and $z_{1}, . . . , z_{8}$ be the observed proportion of traffic that was on bicycles in the residential streets with bike lanes and with no bike lanes, respectively (so y1 = 16/(16 + 58) and z1 = 12/(12 + 113), for example). Set up a model so that the yi’s are independent and identically distributed given parameters $\theta_{y}$ and the $z_{i}$’s are independent and identically distributed given parameters $\theta_{z}$.

(b) Set up a prior distribution that is independent in $\theta_{y}$ and $\theta_{z}$.

Comment: You are looking for a Dirichlet distribution.

Comment: So, Are the Y and Z Dirichlet with $\alpha \sim Gamma(a,b)$? @DaveHarris

Comment: No, Dirichlet prior and multinomial likelihood.